# IP reputation lists of malicious/suspicious IPs (paid or free)

Tags: ip, blacklist

I am looking for (also paid) option to get a list of bad, malicious IPs. Are there some vendors selling those?

So far I found many IP lookup website and lists, but they relate mostly to SPAM.

I want to lookup async if our system was accessed (user logged in) from any of those malicious/suspicious IPs and review this account/possibly block it.

How can I tackle this?

Comment: You are better off describing the specific security question you are trying to solve instead of asking for product recommendations. The former is on topic, but the latter isn't.

Comment: I want to filter out async compromised system accounts, those accessed from BAD IPs. All I find is IPs sending SPAM, but I would like to find IPs belonging to Botnets, used in attacks etc

Comment: If you block some IP, you might end up blocking some domain that user web hosting services that share the same IP.

Comment: Yes, thats why I want to check it asyncronously and flag any accounts for manual review by customer care. Dont want to block anything. There will be false postives, uncertainities, but hopefully I can also catch taken over accounts.

Comment: Any list for "bad actor" IPs are going to go very stale very quickly. And if you are talking about botnets, they tend to be from hacked devices, which means it can be difficult to distinguish between a legitimate user on an IP and the bot.

Answer (score 2):

Brightcloud makes a great product that gets update frequently: https://www.brightcloud.com/

There are a lot of open source lists, but I personally find that they tend to have a lot of stale data.

Answer (score 0):

There is a lot of vendors and probably you will need to check how is the service in terms of money and quality (FP/FN), but I will recommend: 
https://www.spamhaus.org/ and https://www.invaluement.com/

Comment: Hmmm... they seem to be SPAM related. Ideally, would like to get IPs belonging to Botnets, used in Attacks etc. Do you know any sources for those?

Comment: @camp0 the OP specifically is not looking for Spam blacklists